# Windows Communication Foundation Null Reference Error

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I am trying to use Windows Communication Foundation(WCF) for testing purposes in my application and I am getting a null object. I am new to using WCF, so any help would be appreciated.

From what I understand, each host has one service type(class). I have several interfaces and classes I want to test. My goal is to make one master class that has instances of the others, so I don't have to have several hosts running. Below is some of my code.

Host-

```
public class AutomationWCFHost
{
    public ServiceHost host;

    public AutomationWCFHost() {
        Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/MyFun");
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyFun), httpUrl);
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    }

    public void StartWCF() {
        this.host.Open();
    }

    public void StopWCF(){
        this.host.Close();
```

Interfaces -

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyFun {
    [OperationContract]
    string Echo(string msg);

    IDataSources DataSources { [OperationContract]get; [OperationContract]set; }
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataSources {
    [OperationContract]
    void Add(DataSource dataSource);
    [OperationContract]
    void Remove(DataSource dataSource);
}
```

Class - I am trying to make one base class so I don't have to have multiple hosts running.

```
public class MyFun : IMyFun {

    public DataSources _dataSources;

    public MyFun () {
        _dataSources = new DataSources();
    }

    public string Echo(string msg) {
        return msg;
    }

    public IDataSources DataSources { get { return _dataSources; } set {_dataSources = (DataSources)value;} }
}

public class DataSources : IDataSources{
....//Several methods and properties
}
```

Test -

```
public void MyTest() {

        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8090/MyFun");
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        ChannelFactory<IMyFun> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyFun>(binding, address);
        IMyFun channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        Assert.AreEqual("Test", channel.Echo("Test"));
        IDataSources dataSources = channel.DataSources;
        dataSources.Add(newDataSource);         
    }
```

As I step through, it runs the echo method fine, but when it does

```
IDataSources dataSources = channel.DataSources;
```

dataSources is null. This makes it so

```
dataSources.Add(newDataSource);
```

fails due to null exception error.

Comment: You probably need to do something like `channel.get_DataSources`.  Intellisense should tell you for sure, just type `channel.` and see what appears for the available members.

Comment: It's highly unusual to expose a property's accessors as service operations.